# MySQL need sub select or temporary table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables.

```
First table - products
products_id | quantity

1001,1
1002,2
1003,5
1004,4


Second table - products_catalog
products_catalog_id | products_id | partner_channel |active_status

1,1001,amazon,0
2,1001,ebay,0
3,1001,zalando,1
4,1002,amazon,1
5,1002,ebay,0
6,1003,amazon,1
7,1003,ebay,1
8,1003,zalando,1
9,1004,amazon,0
10,1004,ebay,0
11,1004,zalando,0
```

I want to have result of the products id with the condition if this product is not active in any partner channel (active_status = 0)
I was using WHERE filter like this:

```
 SELECT p.products_id, pc.partner_channel, pc.active_status
    FROM products p
      LEFT  JOIN products_catalog pc ON  pc.products_id=p.products_id     
    WHERE pc.active_status='0' 
GROUP BY p.products_id ORDER BY  p.products_id;
```

WHERE active_status = 0, but the result was like this:

```
products_id | partner_channel | active_status
1001,amazon,0
1002,ebay,0
1004,amazon,0
```

I want to have result table products like this:

```
products_id | partner_channel | active_status
1004,amazon,0
```

Because in all partner_channel only this product id (1004) that have active_status = 0.

I think i missed something in the WHERE filter, but didn't have any clue about that. Maybe i should use sub query in when LEFT JOIN to products_catalog?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can try with `GROUP BY pc.products_id `,can you please make a fiddle....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place a condition in the `HAVING` clause like this:

```sql
SELECT products_id
FROM products_catalog
GROUP BY products_id 
HAVING SUM(active_status <> 0) = 0;
```

This query returns all `products_id` values having `active_status = 0` for **all** `partner_channel` they are related to.

You can then use the above query as a derived table to join back to the original tables in order to get the rest of the fields:

```sql
SELECT p.*, pc.*
FROM products p
JOIN products_catalog pc ON pc.products_id=p.products_id  
JOIN (
    SELECT products_id
    FROM products_catalog
    GROUP BY products_id 
    HAVING SUM(active_status <> 0) = 0
) AS g ON g.products_id = p.products_id
ORDER BY p.products_id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e42088/3)

Answer (score 2):

use **Having** function.

```
SELECT p.products_id, ANY_VALUE(pc.partner_channel), ANY_VALUE(pc.active_status)
    FROM products p
      LEFT  JOIN products_catalog pc ON  pc.products_id=p.products_id   
 GROUP BY p.products_id
 having sum(pc.active_status)=0
  ORDER BY  p.products_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
SELECT p.products_id, pc.partner_channel, pc.active_status
    FROM products p
      LEFT  JOIN products_catalog pc ON  pc.products_id=p.products_id     
    WHERE pc.active_status='0' 
GROUP BY p.products_id ORDER BY  p.products_id DESC;
```

Comment: This seems like a copy/paste from my answer. This is not allowed here is SO.